# Prestashop 1.7 Voucher handling

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Quick summary what i try to build.

We are an Promotion / Voucher Cloud Service, where our users can create such Voucher / Promotion with very specific condition and we validate if these are valid.

```
// 1. Catch Voucher Submit Event  --> ?? 
// 2. Connect to API
// 3. Validate Code 
// 4. Get Discount from API
// 5. Create Cart Rule and add()
```

Im stucked at part 1.

**1. How can i attach my code after the user pressed the submit button. I guess there must be a hook or a Function for this.**

Im using Presta 1.7 and so far i build an working Modul which can be installed and have an little form on the back office for API settings.

Thanks in advance!